# Java ee deploy cumstom configuration file

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, configuration-files

Is it possbile to deploy a custom configuration file to the web application server without adding it manually? I'm using glassfish 3.1.2.2 and as an IDE netbeans 7.2

Comment: If not manually, how do you want this file to be added? Who should add it?

Comment: netbeans should add it. I'm not familiar with the deployment process of netbeans and which tools it uses but when I added an xml file in netbeans it wasn't deployed to the server. All other content was deployed just not the file

Comment: Where in you project did you add this XML file?

Comment: I tried to add it inot "Configuration Files" and I also tried to add it into a package where the class is located in which I want to use the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to `/web/WEB-INF` which is under 'Web Pages' in the 'Projects' view of NetBeans.